# How to round a number based on the decimal? (SQL)

Tags: sql

Hello guys my question is this:

I have a rule to validate if a number is greater or equal than .3 I will round to the next number and add another one. Example:

```
1000.3 = 1001 + 1 = 1002
```

If the number is less than `.3` I will only add one:

```
1000.2 = 1001
```

I have been looking for some kind of command in SQL but I had no luck. Hope you could help me.

Thanks!
Ro A.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for?  Probably `ROUND(yourNumber + 1.2,0)` or similar. Also can there be negative numbers? If so what is the rule for those?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Number - FLOOR(Number)) >= .3 
            THEN (CEILING(Number)+1)
            ELSE CEILING(Number)
       END AS NextNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally wrote that this is ANSI, but it's not. However SQL Server and MySQL both support the % operator.

```
DECLARE @one DECIMAL(10, 1) = 1000.3

 SELECT  CASE WHEN @one % CAST(@one AS INT) >= 0.3 THEN CAST(@one as INT) + 1
    ELSE CAST(@one as INT) + 2 END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ROUND(15.193,-1) "Round" FROM DUAL;

     Round
----------
        20
```

Comment: 20 would not be the desired result for 15.193 using the logic in the Question. It would be 16 as the decimal part is less than 0.3 so add 1 to the integer part.

Comment: `DUAL` is not available in SQL Server.

Comment: @MKR the question isn't currently tagged SQL Server.

Comment: @Martin Smith I believe there is a different tag for SQL and SQL SERVER ;)

Comment: @MartinSmith Agree. But just wanted to let Ted knows that his ans is specific to Oracle.